# FolioReader-Android

Tags: android, mobile-development, lib

Здравствуйте, подскажите пожалуйста почему приложение при старте падает

Вот мой класс

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FolioActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(FolioActivity.INTENT_EPUB_SOURCE_TYPE, FolioActivity.EpubSourceType.RAW);
    intent.putExtra(FolioActivity.INTENT_EPUB_SOURCE_PATH, R.raw.niga);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Вот логи..

[image: скриншот логов]

Comment: У вас NPE. Большего из приведённой вами инфы сказать нельзя. Нужно больше подробностей

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, у ридера не получается прочитать Вашу книгу. Если посмотреть [в исходники](https://github.com/FolioReader/FolioReader-Android/blob/master/folioreader/src/main/java/com/folioreader/activity/FolioActivity.java), вероятнее всего не инициализируется поле `mBook` в 164й строке. Советую покопаться [в классе `FileUtil`](https://github.com/FolioReader/FolioReader-Android/blob/master/folioreader/src/main/java/com/folioreader/util/FileUtil.java), начав с метода `saveEpubFile`. Попробуйте сделать то же самое с вашим ресурсом, возможно Вам удастся выяснить, из-за чего не удаётся получить к нему доступ.